# Can recycling python object ids be a problem to a Pickler?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, memoization

I read that pyhton will recycle IDs, meaning that a new object can end up with the ID of one that previously existed and was distroyed.  I also read about [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html):

> The pickle module keeps track of the objects it has already serialized, so that later references to the same object won’t be serialized again. marshal doesn’t do this.

If I hold an instance of a `Pickler` open for several minutes writing to a single file as information comes in, and discard it immediately after calling `Pickler.dump(obj)`, is there a risk that a new `obj` will be given the id of another that's already been written to in the same file and so accidently the wrong thing is written?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no risk of this occurring, because the memo `dict` *includes* the object in question; its lifetime does not end until the pickling is complete and the memo dictionary is cleaned up.

Specifically, in the current implementation, the memoization dictionary maps the `id` of the object to a two-`tuple`, where the first element is the index to use when the memoized value is written a second time, and the second element is the value itself. This is an intentional part of the design, per the comments within the function, which state:

> The object is stored in the Pickler memo so that transient objects are kept alive during pickling.